# Eclipse doesn't recognize my class as a Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I'm trying to instantiate an Fragment to my FragmenteActivity class but Eclipse doesnt let me!

Let me show you:

That is my Fragment Class:

```
public class VendorListFragment extends Fragment {

    private VendorListAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Vendor> vendorList;
    private VendorSQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private ListView listView;

    public VendorListFragment() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vendor_list, container, false);          
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        this.setRetainInstance(true);

        return rootView;
    }
```

So you can see that it extends Fragment, right? But in my FragmentActivity class, shown above, when I code

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_trade_show_vendor_fragment, new VendorListFragment());
```

Eclipse says:

> The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int, VendorListFragment)

So, Eclipse doesn't think my ViewTradeShowActivity is a Fragment, even with the Extends Fragment, what is wrong?!?

See some more code below:

```
public class ViewTradeShowActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    TextView viewTradeShowName;
    TradeShow tradeShow;
    Fragment vendorFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_trade_show);

        tradeShow = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("tradeShow");

        viewTradeShowName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_trade_show_name);
        viewTradeShowName.setText(tradeShow.getName());

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_trade_show_vendor_fragment, new VendorListFragment()); 

    }    
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure to have the correct imports?

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Comment: I'm feeling really dumb right now; That was it, thanks for clearing the dumbness out of my head.